# filter a value from a list via PNP/JS and then store it in a locale variable within SPFx SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, pnpjs

I have a lack of understanding of retrieving a value from a list. I want to use it to build a counter and then increment the counter locally after a button is pressed. After the incrementation I want to write it back to the counter list.

The value is retrieved by using PNP/JS. This works so far. Everytime I want to write it to local variable I get the error message "undefined". I don't know where the problem is coming from and where I need to defined the type.

Here are my code steps so far:

1. First I filter the element with the type ICounterItem:

My defined Item and the retrieving of the specific counter Value. The number should be 2

```
export interface ICounterItem{
    Id: number,
    NewId: number
}

    public ReadCounterValue = async (listTitle: string): Promise<ICounterItem> =>{

     try{
      const response: ICounterItem= await this._sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle(listTitle)
      .items.top(1).filter("Title eq 'TO'")
      .select("Id","NewId")()
      return response;
     }

   catch(e){
      console.log(e);
     }
   }
```

2. Then I want to save the retrieved value in my state (counterID) variable:

   ```
   export interface IListItemsState{
     counterItem: ICounterItem;
     counterID: number
     }
   ```
3. I wrote the constructor and intialize the counterID in the next step with 0

   ```
    constructor(props:ISpTestingfilesystemProps, state: IListItemsState){
     super(props);
     this.state={
        counterID:0
     }
     this._spDataProvider= new SharePointDataProvider();
     this._sp= getSP();
   }
   ```

Then I try to set the value to counterID. The Counter ID should be 2 (See the screenshot)

[image: Counter numeber]

```
 private getCounterValue(): void {
this._spDataProvider.ReadCounterValue("Counter").then((item)=>{  
  console.log("Counter Value: "+ JSON.stringify(item))
  console.log(item.NewId);
  this.setState({
       counterID: item.NewId
  })
})
}
```

When I lock it to the console and try to put it in a div. I get blank and in the console undefined.

I hope you can help me with finding my error.

Best regards

Comment: Try using `console.log(item[0].NewId);`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving array of objects as a result from your SharePoint API call. So, you will have to get the `NewId` from first element/object of array result.

Try using this:

```
public ReadCounterValue = async (listTitle: string): Promise<ICounterItem[]> =>{
    try{
        const response: ICounterItem[] = await this._sp.web.lists
        .getByTitle(listTitle)
        .items.top(1).filter("Title eq 'TO'")
        .select("Id","NewId")()
        return response;
    }

    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

private getCounterValue(): void {
    this._spDataProvider.ReadCounterValue("Counter").then((items)=>{  
        console.log("Counter Value: "+ JSON.stringify(items))
        console.log(items[0].NewId);
        this.setState({
            counterID: items[0].NewId
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi! It's not working. I get the error messagt that the type is of any and it could not find the index of 0.

Comment: now it's working. I needed to define an array in the ReadCounterValue: so Promise<ICounterItem[]> and ICounterItem[]

Comment: Yes, correct. Because your API call returns the array of objects. I have updated the answer with full example.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you!

Comment: Hi @Matthias, can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? Your action on this thread will be greatly appreciated!